# When changing browser size, image gallery leaves a large gap on right side

Tags: html, css

I am creating a image gallery of 300x200 images. The gallery is made of

```
<div id="gallery" >

    <a href="gallery/1.jpg">
        <img src="resized_gallery/gallery001.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="gallery/1.jpg">
        <img src="resized_gallery/gallery002.jpg" />
    </a>
```

etc

The problem is when reducing the browser window it leaves a huge white space to the right.
[image]

How do I stop the white space occurring? Ideally I would like the pictures to go slightly outside of the window before resizing to a smaller column.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REfjm/7/

Comment: We're going to need to see more of your code.  Could you try to recreate the problem in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see your html _and_ css?

Comment: Added JSFiddle link. Closest I could get quickly. Seems to perform the same, leaving a gap to the right when reducing size.

Comment: What do you mean by "go slightly outside of the window before resizing to a smaller column"? How would you like the white space to be filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
You can bring the whole thing to the middle so that it would not look ugly when resized by adding `text-align:center;` inside `#gallery`

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/REfjm/9/)

**Solution 2 :** 
You can increase the max-width of the image just when the images gets clipped into two columns like this --> lets assume your images are getting clipped into two column at width:950px

```
  //this one for changing when it gets converted to two column
    @media  screen and (max-width: 950px) {
           #gallery img{
            max-width:400px; // you can change this according to your needs so that there is only litl white space 
          }
        }
  //this one for changing when it gets converted to one column (we consider 850 to be the width when it gets converted from two column to 1 column)
    @media  screen and (max-width: 850px) {
       #gallery img{
        max-width:600px; 
      }
  }
```

[DEMO FOR THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/REfjm/26/)

Comment: This is what I would do, also.  Not exactly what is being asked for, but definitely what works best.

Comment: Problem is that amount of white space is not fitting with the rest of the theme, I am trying to reduce it to either a 5px margin all around or the smallest white space possible. And I do agree this is a good fix and one I will use if I can not reduce the white space.

Comment: Showing half images while resizing looks more ugly . By the way at what width your image are going into two column  ?

Comment: At around 924px it reduces from three to two. 1230px from four to three.

Comment: @Babyrat I have also added a second solution but you will have to tweak it according to your need so checkout which one to use .

Comment: Your second solution is exactly what I was looking for. That is a perfect fix, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it if I wanted the images to slightly bleed out on the right before dropping to the next row. Modify to taste. Serve.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#gallery {
    width: 120%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/REfjm/12/